# Python script in xcode build phase

Tags: python, swift, xcode

I try to generate code by [GYB](https://nshipster.com/swift-gyb/). I did everything and it works perfectly in a new and clean project. Tests and code are generated in the right way. When I tried to integrate my solution in the main project I got a weird message:

```
line 2: import: command not found
line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Looks like it doesn't see python or smth

Is there any project settings about python or scripts environment?

The main project is like from 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For someone who needs it.

Replace the original part of the script

```
./path/to/gyb
```

with

```
python /path/to/gyb
```

I have no idea why it doesn't recognize python script from the beginning in the old project.